# Initial waiting view controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I need a way of having a initial view controller waiting with an image or something until I download all the information that the apps need.

And once it has finished downloading, go to the real main screen (in my case a `TabBAr Controller`)

I am trying to do it with normal `segues` but I can´t doit unless I embed the waiting controller on a `Navigation Controller`, which I think it isn't the best way.

[image]

Any clue on which is the best way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply u can show MBProgressHUD till now your view info not fully download

Answer (score 0):

The way i would be doing this is by adding a **UIView** containing **UIImageView** and **UIActivityIndicatorView** to it, when you start downloading and removing the view from the view controller when downloading is finished. All by coding

```
    UIView *loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [loadingView setTag:99];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:loadingView.frame];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NAME OF IMAGE"]];
//    [loadingView addSubview:imageView];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [activity setFrame:CGRectMake(imageView.center.x - 10, imageView.center.y - 10, 20, 20)];
    [imageView addSubview:activity];
    [loadingView addSubview:imageView];
    [self.view.window addSubview:loadingView];
```

And when downloading finishes you can remove this view like this

```
[[self.view.window viewWithTag:99] removeFromSuperview];
```

This all is to be done in the first view controller you are showing.